# Unrecognized database format accdb in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2017, oledbconnection

- I am using visual studio community 2017
- Access 2010 - 2016
- I can import an access file I created
- File sent from client contains(tables, queries, forms, macros, and modules)
- Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\jeremiah\Documents\Batching.accdb
- The client sent me another basic file, was able to open without a problem

So I been through all current StackOverFlow solutions for people reporting the unrecognized database error and none of them have been useful.

My only theory is that the database they are using is to complicated to be used as a data source for visual studio.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The error occurs in Open Method?

Comment: I have not tried to programmatically connect, only using add data source

Comment: Install Microsoft Access 2010 database Engine

Comment: I had such problem and I solved this issue only after I saved the database file as access 2003. Open the file in access and go to save as

Comment: @MarcoAntonioQuintal - ALready did that

Comment: check if visual studio is using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4 instead Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12. Jet not works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I may not tell you what the problem is but I solved this issue before by resaving the database file as Microsoft Access 2003. Goto Save Database As Access 2002-2003 (*.mdb) and then use the new file.

Comment: That did it, thought I wish I didn't have to change the format.  I am not sure if that will affect the client's workflow or if they will lose any features.

Answer (score 3):

You need use ACE.OLEDB **32 bits** in Visual studio connection. (click in Advanced... button in Add Conection screen)
[image]

The visual studio try use of Jet.OleDB not more supported.

Comment: That is not what is causing the problem, but thanks for trying to offer a solution